# Name for the reals augmented with an $x$ such that $x^2 = x$

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

If you add an $x$ such that $x^2=-1$ to the reals, you get the complex numbers. If you add an $x$ such that $x^2=0$ to the reals, you get the dual numbers. If you add an $x$ such that $x^2=+1$ to the reals, you get the split complex numbers.

If you add an $x$ such that $x^2=x$ to the reals, you get... what? What's the name for that number system? You know, the one where $e^{a+bx} = e^a + (e^{a+b} - e^a)x$.

Comment: I believe this will be isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}\times \Bbb{R}$. Which incidentally is the same as the split complex numbers.

Comment: I don't understand (sorry if it's just me), but don't $0, 1$ already satisfy that?

Comment: @Soke, I was assuming we were taking $\Bbb{R}[x]/(x^2-x)$.

Comment: @jgon Oh okay, the material is probably just going over my head.

Comment: @Soke 0 and 1 do satisfy $v^2 = v$, but the question is about what you get when you add a *third* solution.

Comment: @Strilanc Interesting. I guess I have abstract algebra to look forward to in my uni years to come!

Comment: Strilanc, here's an idea for a generalization. We start with a poset $P$. We then take the (commutative) $\mathbb{R}$-algebra freely generated by the elements of $P$, and then quotient out by the relations $\{pq=q \mid p,q \in P, p \leq q\}.$ Your algebraic structure is obtained in the special case where $P$ is the poset with a single element $\{x\}$. Other interesting cases occur where $P$ is $\{x_0,x_1,x_2,\cdots\}$ totally-ordered in the obvious way.

Comment: Another idea is to start with a join semilattice $L$, view $L$ as a commutative semigroup, and then take the $\mathbb{R}$-algebra freely generated by this commutative semigroup. Your algebraic structure is obtained in the special case where $L$ is the join semilattice $\{x\}$ defined by $x \vee x =x$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $x^2=x$, then

$$
(2x-1)^2=4x^2-4x+1=4x-4x+1=1
$$

So you actually have the split-complex numbers in disguise.

Comment: Doesn't this just show that we can embed the split complex numbers into the number system of interest? It doesn't show they're isomorphic.

Comment: @goblin: They're both $2$-dimensional...

Comment: It's pretty easy to find an inverse to show the embedding is onto and $1-1$

Comment: Interesting, so it's just a basis change where $j$ = $2x-1$? Good enough for me! Thanks.

Comment: @Strilanc: Yes, exactly. In general, if you try to extend the real numbers by appending something that satisfies a quadratic relation, it always will end up being a disguised version of one of the three systems in your question.

Comment: indeed, adding $x$ so that $x^2+bx+c=0$, the resulting ring must be isomorphic to one of the three listed above, depending on whether $b^2-4c$ is negative, zero, or positive.

Answer (score 3):

Similarly to Micah's answer, but showing an ismorphism to $\Bbb{R}\times \Bbb{R}$, note that

\begin{align}
(a(1-x)+bx)(c(1-x)+dx)
&= ac(1^2-2x+x^2)+(ad+bc)(x-x^2)+bdx^2 \\
&= ac(1-2x+x)+(ad+bc)(x-x)+bdx \\
&=ac(1-x)+bdx.
\end{align}

Therefore the mapping to $\Bbb{R}\times \Bbb{R}$: $\varphi(a(1-x)+bx)=(a,b)$ preserves multiplication. Showing that it preserves addition is easy. Similarly the kernel must be trivial since if $\varphi(a(1-x)+bx)=0$, we have $a=b=0$, so $a(1-x)+bx=0$. Finally, this homomorphism is trivially surjective. Note that the mapping is well defined since $1-x$ and $x$ form a basis.

Answer (score 0):

Such objects are called idempotents. Split-complex numbers have two idempotents, $1/2+j/2$ and $1/2-j/2$.

[Triplex numbers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dvI7dGXFgm8) also have idempotents, for instance, $\frac{1+i+j}2$ and $\frac{2-i-j}2$ (totally 8).

Also, consider the one-point or two-point compactifications of real numbers (the later is called "extended real line", $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$). In both, there is one idempotent, $\infty$, because $\infty^2=\infty$.